# Coordinate projections in D[0,1] continuous

Tags: skorohod-space

In an older article (see [Are coordinate projections in the Skorokhod space continuous?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/284699/are-coordinate-projections-in-the-skorokhod-space-continuous)) the proof is given that the projections are continuous for x=0 and x=1. How can I conclude from $d(f,g)\geq\max\{|f(0)-g(0)|,f(1)-g(1)\}$ that they are continuous?

Comment: What is the definition if $d(f,g)$ ?

Comment: You find the definition in the link